# How can I connect button touch up inside event to View Controller method goBack xCode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8.2

I understand that to connect a delegate outlet to the View Controller in xCode 8.2.1, we can simply drag the open circle to the yellow view controller circle in the connections inspector for a text field, for example. That is easy.

However, I am following a tutorial and they didn't explain how to get a touch up inside event to connect to a View Controller method called goBack.  I don't see methods where I can drag the touch up inside circle to.  I googled around for about 20 minutes and I could not find a solution.  Here's an image showing the desired result:

[image: This is the result I want from the tutorial video I am following, but I don't know how to do it]

Is there any way to do it in storyboard?  Would I have to code up the connection?
Update:  Silly me, I thought that the goBack method was a built in View Controller function.  I was wrong.  I had to connect the button myself to the view controller.swift file.  Thanks Leanne!

Comment: There IS an automatic "go back" functionality if your view controller is embedded into a navigation controller. In your storyboard, click on your view controller. Then, in the menu click on Editor/Embed In/Navigation Controller. Xcode will add a navigation controller. You'll see a "segue" between the navigation controller and your view controller. As you add view controllers, the navigation controller will automatically give you a "back" button. You'll probably get to that eventually in your tutorial. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While on the storyboard, and with the correct view selected, look in the upper right corner of Xcode. You'll see a button with two rings intertwined:
[image]

Click that icon to "Show the Assistant Editor". (This brings up your view controller.)

Now, control-drag from the button on the storyboard to the view controller code where you want to place the action (your `goBack` method).

You'll see the method get highlighted with a blue bar. Let go, and that method will now be tied to your button.

When you're done, the method should have `@IBAction` in front of it, and a round target symbol in the gutter area. The target symbol indicates the method is tied to the storyboard.

Your code should look like this:

[image: IBAction connected symbol]`@IBAction func goBack()
    {
        // code
    }`